# Why are my .wasm files not served correctly when invoked with web-workers in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, webassembly, sql.js

Right now I try work with the sql.js library and implement a web-worker that creates a SqLite database in the browser. The library itself consists of `.wasm files.` Right now these files are in the public directory under a custom assets folder (i.e. `sql-wasm.wasm` and `worker-sql-wasm.js` (please see their documentation for more information).

In one of my pages (db.js) in the pages directory I currently try to implement the worker like this:

```js
const createDb = () => {
    const worker = new Worker(
        new URL("public/assets/worker.sql-wasm.js", import.meta.url)
    );
    worker.onerror = (e) => console.log("Worker error: ", e);
};
```

When calling that function I receive following errors:
[image]

As the following error

```
worker.sql-wasm.js:2343 failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0
```

indicates not a `.wasm` file, but a plain html file was served (As 3c 21 44 4f reconcile to <DOC (see [this](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/issues/1031#issuecomment-498314525) similar issue for reference).

The file itself got served under the following url `http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/sql-wasm.wasm.`

[image: See the log of the browser for the original URL]

As both the .wasm file itself and its corresponding .js file are in the public directory I would expect the correct files to be served.

(As this behaviour seems to be a bug I filed a isse [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38278) as well.

### Update 04.07.22

Apparently the `.wasm` file does not get served correctly into the `.next/static/chunks` directory. When copying the file after running `npm run dev` the web-worker is invoked and working correctly. The 404 error thus stems from the fact that the requested path by the worker itself (`worker.sql-wasm.js`) `http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/sql-wasm.wasm` is not existent and thus the server responds with a 404.

I played around with different web-pack configs, but as my knowledge at this front is rather superficial I only had limited (i.e. none at all) success.
What config here is necessary that the `.wasm` file is served correctly?

Comment: Look at the HTTP Status code which is not shown in your question. Either you have a file not found, a CORS error, or a similar problem preventing the download of the actual Wasm file.

Comment: It basically tries to redirect to a page that not exists. So it's a 404. I do not understand why though.

Comment: Edit your question and show the URI of the original request and the redirect. I noticed you are using **..** in the URI. Specify the full path and not relative paths.

Comment: @JohnHanley please see my update above.

Comment: Some server implementations require having the MIME types set up to serve certain types of files and return the content-type `application/wasm`. For example, Apache requires changes to serve Wasm files. I wrote an article for Apache which might help you see if your server requires similar changes: https://www.jhanley.com/pyscript-apache-web-server-setup/

Comment: When copied manually into the output directory of Next.js the file gets served correctly. The main problem seems to be that Next.js is not putting the ```.wasm``` file into the output directory but only its worker ```worker.sql-wasm.js```.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? @Mxngls

Comment: In the end I just ended up fetching the `.wasm` file from a CDN where these are hosted instead of just using the bundled file. The documentation from the library I was using (sqlJS) at that time states this as an alternative [approach](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js#usage).